# htaccess status codes list

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are plenty of apache status codes from 1xx to 5xx, but looking for a list only status codes are used in .htaccess file with these following 3 redirectives

1. Redirect
2. RedirectMatch
3. RewriteRule

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read in the Apache documentation:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r

> Any valid HTTP response status code may be specified, using the syntax [R=305], with a 302 status code being used by default if none is specified. The status code specified need not necessarily be a redirect (3xx) status code. However, if a status code is outside the redirect range (300-399) then the substitution string is dropped entirely, and rewriting is stopped as if the L were used.

And here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

> Other status codes can be returned by giving the numeric status code as the value of status. If the status is between 300 and 399, the URL argument must be present. If the status is not between 300 and 399, the URL argument must be omitted. The status must be a valid HTTP status code, known to the Apache HTTP Server.